# How do I know what manufacturer's parts are on a gun?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've seen loading tips like "assault rifles with a Vladof barrel fire faster as you keep the trigger held"; this clearly refer to the "Spinigun" triple gatling barrel assault rifles. Aside from that and the Elemental accessory (which I believe is exclusively made by Maliwan) I don't really know how to recognize which parts come from other manufacturers. Note that these parts show up on *other manufacturer's guns*, I've seen Bandit and Jakob's Spiniguns and elemental guns from everyone but Jakob's.

Are there other parts that are made by specific manufacturers that show up on guns? Most parts appear to be exclusive to a manufacturer's guns (e.g. Tediore's clean, mass-produced aesthetic), but it's implied certain parts can be on other manufacturer's guns, like the Vladof rifle barrel. How can I recognize them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infographics of various weapon parts:

- [SMGs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQcpQ.jpg)
- [Rocket Launchers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDKGI.jpg)
- [Sniper Rifles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wisqa.jpg)
- [Shotguns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQj7P.jpg)
- [Pistols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXjzX.jpg)
- [Assault Rifles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4wUu.jpg)

---

Source and higher-resolution version of images from Reddit user Zikel's "Weapon parts infographic" series of posts at /r/Borderlands:

- [Weapon parts infographic [#1] SMGs](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/18g0pa/weapon_parts_infographic_1_smgs/)
- [Weapon parts infographic [#2] Rocket launchers](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/18ioop/weapon_parts_infographic_2_rocket_launchers/)
- [Weapon parts infographic [#3] Sniper rifles](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/18l18h/weapon_parts_infographic_3_sniper_rifles/)
- [Weapon parts infographic [#4] Shotguns](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/18ozgj/weapon_parts_infographic_4_shotguns/)
- [Weapon parts infographic [#5] Pistols](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/1931ph/weapon_parts_infographic_5_pistols/)
- [Weapon parts infographic [#6] Assault rifles](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/196z3m/weapon_parts_infographic_6_assault_rifles/)

Answer (score 4):

It seems the only way to check in-game is to visually recognize the parts; some are more obvious than others, for example Vladof Sniper and Pistol barrels are always double, rotating barrels.

You can check the manufacturers' parts directly using [Gibbed's Borderlands 2 Save Editor](http://blog.gib.me/2015/10/31/borderlands-2-save-editor-revision-256/) (link is to the most recent version *as of now*, it's actively updated and I don't think there's a single page to always get the latest version).

Basically you just load up your character's save file, go to "bank" or "backpack" and you can check out your stored/current gear and what stats they have. You can also of course edit them, but that's not required (and make sure to save your game before doing any editing yada yada yada).

For example here's a Maliwan legendary Norfleet clearly showing parts from multiple manufacturers:

[image]

Different parts have different manufacturer options so there's really no easy way to tell what's what without looking through this tool (or recognizing the parts after becoming familiar with them via this tool).

Note that the tool rapidly becomes out of date (after each patch) and may not work properly until a new version is released after a patch. DLCs tend to break it since they introduce new guns.

If you're not sure how to use the editor, guides for the current version can usually be found in the Se7enSins forums for Borderlands 2 Modding.  A [stickied thread](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/gibbeds-save-editor-revision-256.862789/) on there right now has a compilation of various related threads.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Gibbed's Save Editor, a most useful tool.  Added in some edits in case others swing by updating to the most recent version and pointing to guides since the youtube video was taken down (though edits are in peer review as I type this)

Answer (score 2):

The guns are always made by just one company.

**Vladof** guns (and therefore also Vladof barrels) have the highest firerates. **Tediore** always have the explosive reload. **Bandit** guns (the ones with the horrible spelling) have the largest magazines. **Maliwan** guns are always elemental (and in general very good). **Jakobs** guns are old-style high damage (the revolvers that fire as fast as you can pull the trigger). **Hyperion** guns are more accurate the longer the trigger is held. **Dahl** guns aways fire in bursts when aiming down sights. **Torgue** guns always deal explosive damage.

This does not mean that Vladof guns can't have elemental effects for example. A manufacturers gun will always have the classic manufacturer effect though.

**Additional info**: Guns name prefixes (such as "Perma-Sharp SMG") are dependent on certain gun accessorys. These are effects/modifiers like 50% more melee damage. Here is a complete list: [Strength Gamer Guide: 'Borderlands 2' Accessory Prefixes List](http://www.realsg.com/2012/09/guide-borderlands-2-accessory-prefixes.html)

Hope I managed to help, all based on personal experience as a level 50 (as of 6 days ago^^).

Comment: Not sure this is true; the "Vladof barrel" thing doesn't make sense if they're only on Vladof guns, they'd just say "vladof assault rifle", plus they're referring to the spinning barrels, which are availible from more than Vladof.

Comment: This may be a miswording of "barrels of Vladof guns", or spinning barrels were once exclusive to Vladof, but were changed later. If BL1 scheme is of any relation, manufacturer is a category independent of weapon parts (though parts do depend of manufacturer). I'd say - consider this text to be inaccurate until we get some data mined that explicitly contradicts that.

Comment: I'm rewriting it a little bit. I'm still sure that all guns only have one manufacturer. They do have many different effects that are usually the hallmarks of other manufacturers (like my vladof armored sniper rifle).

Comment: Hm this actually doesn't appear to be true: http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Aftermarket#Aftermarket

Comment: The wiki actually calls bs on the aftermarket idea in the talk page. It seems to be false. http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Unique#Aftermarket

Comment: Not on grounds that the parts aren't from different manufacturers though...several other pages like this one (http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Injector) refer to having parts from a specific manufacturer

Comment: To the confused: While it is true that each specific gun is manufactured by only one firm (e.g., the Trespasser sniper is not made by more than one corporation), that weapon may be produced using parts from more than a single company. I suspect the misapprehension may stem from ubiquitous Borderlands One warnings about mixing parts (but, at the moment I cannot recall whether or not those cautions are indeed founded in fact).

Answer (score 0):

The body/action of a gun determines it’s manufacture. So it may have parts/accessories from 3/4 weapons manufacturers but the gun’s actual body/action will be it’s manufacturer’s