# Do manufacturer's traits apply to E-Tech guns?

Tags: borderlands-2

Related: [How do I know what manufacturer's parts are on a gun?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86196/how-do-i-know-what-manufacturers-parts-are-on-a-gun)

The accepted answer to the linked question indicates that all guns by a particular manufacturer share a common trait: Tediore guns always explode when you reload them, Hyperion guns become more accurate the more you shoot, and so on.

**Does this apply to E-tech weapons as well?**  For example, will a Railer Sniper Rifle made by Dahl shoot differently than a Railer Sniper Rifle made by Maliwan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; the [Borderlands Wiki page for e-Tech notes the unique traits of each](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/E-Tech). E-tech guns actually vary slightly more based on manufacturer; the names and special effects can be different based on manufacturer; for example the PRAMZMA CANNON, which is unsurprisingly a Bandit gun, is a unique class of E-Tech rocket launcher. But in addition to *extra* special manufacturer-specific stuff, Tediore E-Tech explodes on reload, Hyperion E-Tech stabilizes with recoil, etc.

Interestingly Jakobs and Torgue don't appear to make E-Tech guns, ever. This is probably due to almost all E-Tech guns being elemental; I've seen exactly one non-elemental E-Tech gun (a BlASSter AR, IIRC, from Zed's quest introducing you to E-Tech) and zero explosive E-Tech guns.

Comment: There is a Torgue E-Tech and Jakobs *does* make element guns now. I have a Jakob's Acid Shotgun.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they do.  I have a Dahl E-Tech SMG that has burst fire when scoped.  I'd imagine other manufacturing bonuses also apply to other e-tech weapons.